# Integrating Solr with FrontEnd JS frameworks

Tags: solr

Anyone has thoughts on integrating Solr with a front end JS framework to perform search queries directly on Solr.

What are the disadvantages/risks of using this approach vs a traditional approach of using the Sitecore.ContentSearch API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Potential risks:

1. Security issue by exposing Solr Endpoint
2. Sitecore upgrade compatibility - Sitecore API *should* abstract Solr version / changes in indexing items.
3. Solr result not respecting security /workflow state etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use SOLR directly from the front end, you must have to expose SOLR publically. Definitely it is a security issue.

1. This way you will be exposing the Sitecore content structure to the public.
2. Your entire content would be exposed having who created, when got created... etc

Better approach is to go for microservices approach:

1. You can abstract the SOLR content
2. At any point of time you can easily change and easy to track impact
3. If require to access from front end, you can expose publicaly as well. It would not have security issue.
4. Here you would have more control like what do you want to expose and what not. If content require authentication, you can implement the same on MicroService level.
5. Easily can be consumed by any other applicaiton (mobile app or other application)